# Why zsh alias not working with file path?

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I worked with Laravel, I used to have alias `pa="php artisan"`, then use it for console commands like `pa serve` insted of `php artisan serve` .

But when I have created similar alias for Symfony `sy="php bin/console"`. And try to `sy server:start` it doesn't work, while `php bin/console server:start` is working.
I did `source ~./zshrc`. And rebooted system too.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You are using `bin` as a relative path (which may be wrong depending on which directory you are). Try to use `alias sy="php <absolute-path>/bin/console"`. Although it does not make much sense (since the standard command is working), you may try this solution.

Comment: It didn't work either, but it turned out I had extra a space and it was the problem:)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had a space before the quote in `.zshrc` file. Like so `alias sy= "php bin/console"`. Once I deleted it, it start to work.
Also good way to check if command is set `which sy`, which should return `sy: aliased to php bin/console`.